# Proving $ \frac{1-(e^{-2})^x}{1-e^{-2}} \ge x $, for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Tags: inequality

How to prove that, for any real number $0 \le x \le 1$, this inequality holds ?
$$
\frac{1-(e^{-2})^x}{1-e^{-2}} \ge x
$$
I tried using wolfram alpha to solve for getting some idea, but the exact solution is very complex : here is [the link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-e%5E%28-2x%29%29%2F%281-e%5E-2%29%3E%3Dx).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove that the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1-e^{-2x}}x$ is decreasing. Hence, $f(x) \geq f(1)$

Answer (score 1):

The function 
$$f(x)=\frac{1-(e^{-2})^x}{1-e^{-2}}-x$$
is concave and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.